# Why only one usb camera shows two Video4Linux devices?

Tags: camera

I bought a new usb webcamera,plug it .

```
ls -l /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Nov 21 10:57 /dev/video0
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Nov 21 10:57 /dev/video1
```

Why only one usb camera shows two Video4Linux devices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Very shortly**
Your application should use `/dev/video0`, for usual stuff, as `/dev/video1` gives you meta-data image, to be used by algorithms, to improve image quality.

**A bit more deeply**

Look at the `Device caps` section, as they are different for both devices:

```
$ v4l2-ctl -D -d /dev/video0
...
Device Caps   : 0x04200001
    Video Capture
    Streaming
    Extended Pix Format

$ v4l2-ctl -D -d /dev/video1
...

Device Caps   : 0x04A00000
    Streaming
    Extended Pix Format
```

The device caps is documented as follows:

```
  * @device_caps:  capabilities accessed via this particular device (node)
```

The bits, that are different for these are:

```
 #define V4L2_CAP_VIDEO_CAPTURE     0x00000001 # bit 1
 #define V4L2_CAP_META_CAPTURE      0x00800000 # bit 23
```

> The applications need to check this in order to know what kind of buffer it will receive, as this should be used by the streaming ioctls: VIDIOC_REQBUFS, VIDIOC_QBUF, VIDIOC_DQBUF

Read more about this discussion from https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=199575